# Why is __ember_meta__ getting added to my vanilla javascript ember-data property?

Tags: ember.js

I have a model that has an attribute I define as follows:

```
aux: Ember.DS.attr()
```

So there's no transformation going on. And when I first load the model, when I do a model.get('aux'), the result is a vanilla javascript object.

But somewhere along the line my application is doing something that adds a bunch of extra properties to the object like `__ember_meta__`. This is interfering with my attempt to recursively clone the object, because it enters an infinite loop.

I'm not too concerned about my infinite loop problem, but rather I'd like to understand under the hood what I'm doing that's causing Ember to transform my vanilla javascript object.

It's not an `Ember.Object` instance, at least according to `Ember.Object.detectInstance(aux)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [Transform](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html) to handle `raw` properties to make sure Ember doesn't do anything to them.
 1. At first, you create a directory `transforms` which is located alongside other directories like routes, components and etc. Then you create a file `raw.js` inside of it with this content:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return serialized;
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return deserialized;
    }
});
```

2. Then you just use in your model `aux: DS.attr('raw')`

UPDATE
According to this [article](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2014/05/31/ember-meta/) `meta` object exists in order to track bindings and observations, so it seems to me, that you might have observers/computed properties which observe this `aux` property and this causes the creation of `meta` object inside your model instance.

Comment: I believe this used to be necessary, but now this is the exact behavior when no type is specified. I looked into this and it seems unrelated to my problem.

Comment: Updated my answer, not 100% sure that this is your issue, but I think you should be looking into articles about this `meta` object and its purpose to find out what happens under the hood.